# How to check HomeButton Click or Google Advertisement is click by user?

Tags: android, onpause, home-button

Any One help me for Provide Exit message to User when User click on Home Button?

I used onPause() method but the Problem is that when User click on google ad then onPause method is called and Message is display to User.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to display the message only when the User presses the HOME BUTTON?

Answer (score 1):

you can Override this one:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Home button pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                     
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.But this method is not called in My Samsung google nexus 4.1 and Htc wildfire 2.2.

Comment: you need to use it in an activity class, in the same place of you onCreate()

Comment: when i clicked keydown then above method is called but i want to called when user click on Home button.

Comment: this method is called onKeyDown event, with the if condition you can do what you want if the specific KeyEvent is the Home button.

here a better example [link](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.it/2011/03/example-code-for-onkeydown-listener-in.html)

Comment: Back button is worked in your link but Home button is not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i am a little late, but for those who need it, you can NOT intercept the HOME button click, otherwise this could be bad, for other reasons, you have to find another way, i my self am still looking for it